# style Issue with Firefox

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net, firefox

I am using the below mentioned code for button `mouseover` event. This particular code fixes the position of the text for the `mouseover` event. It works fine for Chrome and IE. But somehow there seems to be an issue with Firefox. In case of Firefox the position is not getting fixed.

Could someone guide me whats wrong in this.

```
<div id="DownloadHelp" runat="server" style="background-color:white; position:fixed; opacity:0; top:100px; z-index:11; color:blue; font-size:small; background-color:silver; border:thin">
    Merge all selected Files
</div>

<asp:button onmouseover="display()" onmouseout="fadeHelp()" id="singleFileDownload" Width="140px" Enabled="false" onclick="SingleFileSelections" runat="server" Text="Merge and Download"></asp:button>

function display() 
{
    document.getElementById("DownloadHelp").style.opacity = "1";
    var x = event.clientX;
    var y = event.clientY;
    document.getElementById("DownloadHelp").style.top = y - 30;
    document.getElementById("DownloadHelp").style.left = x + 10;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Firefox, `event` object isn't exposed to global object.

Do this:

```
function display(event) 
{
    document.getElementById("DownloadHelp").style.opacity = "1";
    var x = event.clientX;
    var y = event.clientY;
    document.getElementById("DownloadHelp").style.top = y - 30;
    document.getElementById("DownloadHelp").style.left = x + 10;
}
```

And this:

```
<asp:button onmouseover="display(event)" onmouseout="fadeHelp()" id="singleFileDownload" Width="140px" Enabled="false" onclick="SingleFileSelections" runat="server" Text="Merge and Download"></asp:button>
```